# images in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-widget

this is my main.xml file

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView  android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the first photo:"
        />

    <ImageViewGroup 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView 

    android:id="@+id/pc1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"


        />

    <ImageView

    android:id="@+id/pc2"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"


        />


        </ImageViewGroup>

         <RatingBar 

         android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"/>


/    LinearLayout>`
```

i m trying to create a group that will be including from 2 images at vertical orientation.If it was radio button i could create a .what i must use for images?(here i tried ImageViewGroup but its wrong!!)thanks!!

Comment: at the top of the page it will be writing "this is my first photos",then i will have two photos side by side and at the bottom of the page will be a rating bar!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was a bit hard to understand but is the following pseudocode what you are looking for?

```
<LinearLayout vertical>
  <TextView/>
  <LinearLayout horizontal>
    <ImageView/>
    <ImageView/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <Rating...>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Consider checking the checkbox next to your post. It encourages people to answer your questions when you mark them as Answered :)